# How to use CKEditor in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, angular-forms, ckeditor5

1. I install CKEditor using `npm install ng2-ckeditor` this command.
2. Then add `ckeditor.js` in my `index.html`
3. Then import `import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';` in `app.module.ts`
4. And then use CKEditor in my HTML page

   ```
    <ckeditor ngModel="{{ckeditorContent}}" formControlName="circular_contents" [config]="{uiColor: '#99000'}" [readonly]="false" debounce="500" debounce="500">
    </ckeditor>
   ```
5. At that time i get the error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined`

Now how can i use CKEditor in my HTML page.

Comment: are you using webpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

everything is ok just include **ckeditor** cdn link in your index.html page, don't download ckeditor.js.

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using angular 4, so please change syntax of ngModel to [(ngModel)].

like this:

```
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="templateConversionDTO.htmlContent"
                name="myckeditor" required debounce="500"> </ckeditor>
```

and don't forget to add **CDN of Ckeditor** in your   **Index.html** file, this is important.

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
```